# Android studio - How to save an image to SECONDARY_STORAGE

Tags: android, android-studio, android-storage

I want to save an image to `SECONDARY_STORAGE` (Not saved to phone memory, which android understands is SdCard ), this is code:

In the `manifests` file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

Java code:

```
public void Clickdownload(View v) {

    Bitmap myImage = GetImageBitmapFromUrl();
    String path = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE") + "/";
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
        File file = new File(path, "nameImage.jpg");
        out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        myImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

}
```

When I run with Debug I get this error

> Error at: 
>     myImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, out);

and it didn't save.

This is the code for reading image from sd card :

```
String path =System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE")+"/myImage/";

File imgFile = new File(path);
if(imgFile.exists())
{
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
    ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
}
```

When I use:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
```

I can save an image to the phone memory.

I can save images from my camera and copy images from my computer on my SdCard, so I do not think this is a `Read only` SdCard. I tried with many types SdCards but it does not work.
I am using android 5.1.1.